# File not showing up in tmp directory when I upload a file from an HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, forms, file, upload, tmp

I have an issue as my file is not showned in the tmp folder after submitting my form.

Here is my form:

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="photo">Choisissez une photo</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo">
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the var_dump($_FILES) result after the submission of the form:

```
array (size=1)
  'photo' => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string 'imgPlaceHolder.jpg' (length=18)
      'full_path' => string 'imgPlaceHolder.jpg' (length=18)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phprxpkYx' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 153687
```

But my "/tmp" directory doesn't contain this file....

Many thanks for any help you could provide!

Cédric

I have tried many var_dump and check the PHP forums but found nothing helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I just left my questions in case someone has to deal with the same issue:

To sum up, I did:

```
$uploadDir = '/Assets/';
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['photo']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempo`enter code here`File, $uploadFile);
```

But my error was on the path, it has to be a relative path without any beginning slash in front of "Assets", given this first line: `$uploadDir = 'Assets/'`;